# What causes an update of an unordered list in a Blazor component with data-binding on an input field?

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

I'm following an ASP.NET Core 6.0 tutorial from this link:  [Build a Blazor todo list app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/build-a-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server).

Here's the code for the Blazor Todo component:

```
@page "/todo"

<PageTitle>Todo</PageTitle>

<h1>Todo</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>@todo.Title</li>
    }
</ul>

<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="AddTodo">Add todo</button>

@code {
    private List<TodoItem> todos = new();
    private string? newTodo;

    private void AddTodo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

What causes the unordered list to be invoked when a todo is added?

This code is not within an event handler, so my natural assumption would be that the only time the flow of control reaches it is during page load/refresh in the browser, what is the invocation mechanism for the unordered list?

Answer (score 1):

Your razor markup is turned into C# code when it compiles.

That code is in a method called BuildRenderTree and that is called whenever Blazor runs a rendering cycle.

When you change the `input` value or click the `button` - because they are bound to c# code, Blazor will automatically trigger a rendering cycle, and so your code in `BuildRenderTree` will run.

This does not mean that the DOM will always update - there is a `diffing` stage where it compares the new tree to the existing one and only update the browser DOM when there is a change.